# Is there a way to include everything that's in /assets/javascripts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include

As it says on the tin. It seems like `javascript_include_tag :all` includes `/assets/all.js` instead of all of them.

Is there a way to just include everything there plus all the subfolders?

Comment: Yes, this is in fact one of the major purposes of the asset pipeline. Use manifests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use the default generated `application.js` ?

**/app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Take a note on the last line: `//= require_tree .` That should include all your javascript.

**/app/view/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

> The require_tree directive tells Sprockets to recursively include all
>   JavaScript files in the specified directory into the output. These
>   paths must be specified relative to the manifest file. You can also
>   use the require_directory directive which includes all JavaScript
>   files only in the directory specified, without recursion.